# How to get date in specific format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to have the dateformat in this format: 2015-08-04T00:00:00Z.

so first year, month, day.

```
 beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                                var dt = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date, "getDate")                               
                                return [$('#form_one3 > option:gt(0)[value="' + dt + 'T00:00:00Z"]').length != 0];

                            },


                            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                                var dt = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText, "getDate")
                                alert(dt);

                                var hallo = $("#form_inp1").val() + 'T00:00:00Z';
                                alert(dateText);
                                alert(hallo);


                                //$("#form_inp1").datepicker("getDate");
                                //alert($("#form_inp1").formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText, "getDate")


                            },
```

But If I do an alert(dateText) I see the format as: 4-8-2015 and it has to be: 2015-08-04.

Thank you

If I try it like this:

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                                dateText = dateText.split("-");
                                dateText = new Date('' + dateText[2] + '-' + dateText[1] + '-' + dateText[0] + '');
                                alert(dateText);
}
```

I get invalid date

So this  `var hallo = $("#form_inp1").val() + 'T00:00:00Z';`

returns: 4-8-2015T00:00:00Z . But it has to be:2015-08-04T00:00:00Z.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you set the date format as your date picker option?

Comment: I try that, because:   var dt = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date, "getDate")    this gives the correct date. But if I do this: $("#form_inp1").val() + 'T00:00:00Z'; I get it in the incorrect format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick fix is to change the date format using plain Javascript. This can be achieved by following script.

```
dt= dt.split("-");
dt = new Date('' + dt[2] + '-' + dt[1] + '-' + dt[0] + '');
```

to add zero in case the day, month and year is below 10, use following method.

```
function AddTrailingZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) { i = "0" + i };  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

Let me know if you have any question related to the code snippet above.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad that I was able to help :)